# Is there any way to stop forwarding payments through my LDK node?

Tags: lightning-routing, lightning-development-kit

I can't seem to find a config option for discarding all forwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's deliberately no way to refuse to forward payments over "public" channels because that's the definition of a "public" channel - one which you are saying you want to accept forwards over.

If you have opted to open private channels (not announced) then  `accept_forwards_to_priv_channels` is what you want (and keep the channels private!).

You can read more about that in our API docs.
https://docs.rs/lightning/0.0.113/lightning/util/config/struct.UserConfig.html#structfield.accept_forwards_to_priv_channels

Comment: This question was originally asked by deb.dasit2013 and answered by Matt Corallo on Discord

Comment: There is a bit of a leap in the explanation between public channels being meant for forwarding, and the recommended setting for private channels. Could you perhaps fill in a bit more context?

Comment: By default LDK opens private channels unless setting the announced_channel flag to true. There is no option for discarding all forwards for publicly announced channels. A user must ensure the channel is private from the outset and accept_forwards_to_priv_channels, generally HTLC intercept will be supported soon.